# Running python code on CUDA

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, cuda

While trying to run this code https://wltrimbl.github.io/2014-06-10-spelman/intermediate/python/04-multiprocessing.html on my GPU system which has 300 cores, i used the comment with tf.device('/GPU:0') on the beginning of code. But found that it does not run on GPU. Then i tried

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.device('/GPU:0'): # for run in GPU
         init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
          # initializing all variables
           sess = tf.Session(
            config=tf.ConfigProto(
             intra_op_parallelism_threads=1))
```

Does this code run in GPU? or is there any method for run a python code on GPU.

Comment: Go for PyCUDA instead of CUDA

Comment: How many more times are you going to try asking this question?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No, it won't run without a GPU optimized version of TensorFlow.

Python multiprocesing is for CPU only.
TensorFlow GPU is available (see here https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/gpu-accelerated-applications/tensorflow/). The Tensorflow GPU implementation is using CUDA with cuDNN under the hood.

To run your own Python script on GPU, you need to use a library like PyCUDA or Cupy which use the CUDA API under the hood as well.

Comment: PyCUDA and CuPy don't allow Python code to run on the GPU. The only current way to do that is via the Numba compilation system.